# Google Maps for iOS SDK Marker Order (stacking) + Ground Anchor problems

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

Anyone figured out yet any way to control the z-order for GMSMarker markers in the Google Maps for iOS SDK?  My maps look great, but I have a bad feeling that this functionality isn't supported yet...

I dug through the header files a little, hoping for some undocumented goodies... and poked through the debugger a little.  Nada.

**Also:** I'm using marker.groundAnchor (a CGPoint property of MKMarker) to handle the fact that my custom marker images have offset ground anchors.  This works great, but with the side effect that their location appears to be offset!  In other words:  if you place an image with a non-centered ground anchor, and don't set groundAnchor, the marker will appear to move as the map is zoomed.  This is expected.  However, if you do set the groundAnchor property the image will appear properly locked in place on the ground... but is now offset substantially from where it is supposed to be!  I think this is a bug.

Comment: There's a feature request to add a z-index here: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5294

Answer (score 0):

The Z-index feature is part of the google maps sdk for ios **Version 1.4.0 - July 2013**

Features list mentions:

```
Added a zIndex property on all overlays. Z-Indexes are calculated in two groups: GMSMarkers and all other overlays.
```